# What is the difference between the return of fft / fft2 applied to a matrix?

Tags: python, fft

In the following program, I would like to compute the fast Fourier transform of a given field given by U. what is the difference between the returned values for fft and for fft2? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, cos, pi

nx=3
ny=3

px=2*pi
py=2*pi

qx=1.0*px/(nx-1)
qy=1.0*py/(ny-1)

x = np.linspace(0,px,nx)
y = np.linspace(0,py,ny)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

U=cos(X)*sin(Y)

#compite fft's
Uh1=np.fft.fft(U)

Uh2=np.fft.fft2(U)

print('For fft')
print(Uh1)

print('For fft2')
print(Uh2)

#What is the difference between Uh1 and Uh2? Thank you!
```

Here is what I get:

```
For fft
[[  0.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j   0.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j
0.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j]
[  1.22464680e-16 +0.00000000e+00j   1.22464680e-16 +2.12115048e-16j
1.22464680e-16 -2.12115048e-16j]
[ -2.44929360e-16 +0.00000000e+00j  -2.44929360e-16 -4.24230095e-16j
-2.44929360e-16 +4.24230095e-16j]]
For fft2
[[ -1.22464680e-16 +0.00000000e+00j  -1.22464680e-16 -2.12115048e-16j
-1.22464680e-16 +2.12115048e-16j]
[  6.12323400e-17 -3.18172572e-16j   6.12323400e-16 -2.12115048e-16j
-4.89858720e-16 -4.24230095e-16j]
[  6.12323400e-17 +3.18172572e-16j  -4.89858720e-16 +4.24230095e-16j
6.12323400e-16 +2.12115048e-16j]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the values returned from each? The `numpy` documentation?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes. I have looked at the documentation but I would like to know what is the difference in the returned results for these two functions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please I have just added some details about the question! Thank you

Comment: If the description of the functions don't tell you what you seek. Then this i think this is more of a math\physics question than a programming question.

Comment: Yes @M4rtini In fact there is another method to know which one correspond really to the DFT of U. I will compare the energy spectrum computed in the Fourier space on the basis of U and V with the energy obtained directly in the physical space. In fact, I would like to find the energy cascade relative to my velocity (Taylor vortices) i.e. (the energy for each wavenumber). Thank you for your precious help!

Comment: Might have more luck in one of the related site like http://physics.stackexchange.com/ i don't know enough of that area of physics to answer that with confidence.

Answer (score 2):

docstring of the np.fft module.

```
Standard FFTs
-------------

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated/

   fft       Discrete Fourier transform.
   ifft      Inverse discrete Fourier transform.
   fft2      Discrete Fourier transform in two dimensions.
   ifft2     Inverse discrete Fourier transform in two dimensions.
   fftn      Discrete Fourier transform in N-dimensions.
   ifftn     Inverse discrete Fourier transform in N dimensions.
```

Plotting the two matricies gives this if you wan't to visualize the differences. I do not know enough about fft's to even know if it makes any sense to plot them this way.

[image]

[image]

```
plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(Uh1.real.ravel())
plt.title("1 - real")
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(Uh2.real.ravel())
plt.title("2 - real")

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot(Uh1.imag.ravel())
plt.title("1 - imaginary")
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.plot(Uh2.imag.ravel())
plt.title("2 - imaginary")

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.hist(Uh1.real.ravel())
plt.title("1 - real")
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.hist(Uh2.real.ravel())
plt.title("2 - real")

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.hist(Uh1.imag.ravel())
plt.title("1 - imaginary")
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.hist(Uh2.imag.ravel())
plt.title("2 - imaginary")
```

Comment: Thank you for that! In fact, I can't either now which one should be used in order to compute the DFT of my field U. I can even understand why there are huge values is the domain boundaries for fft2! Thank you anyway for your time and efforts!

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik added the histograms of the two matrices also, if that helps any.